# Different invoice template depending on payment gateway?

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

We have an client who uses two payment gateways - they have a requirement that some types of payments (contributions) use one payment gateway, and other types of contributions use another payment gateway. The resulting invoices will need a different header and contact information.

Has anyone achieved something like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a client with different payment gateways we sidestepped the issue by having different Contribution pages for each - since one was for a c4 and one for a c3 entity and used

```
{if $contributionPageId == X}
```

Comment: Either that - or create distinct FinancialTypes to be invoiced differently; For sure FinancialTypes are available in the template

Answer (score 0):

The invoice templates are at `Administer > Communications > Message Templates` in the `System Workflow Messages` tab.

They use smarty so can have some fairly complex logic, although I don't know whether Payment Processor is passed to the templates.  You could try some [smarty debugging](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#in-smarty-template-files) to see what is available.

Comment: What I have done in a project is to retrieve the missing data with api calls in the template. Documentation on how to use the api in smarty is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/usage/#smarty

Comment: Good point @JaapJansma-CiviCooP - I've also done that and it works well.